# Texmaker: Read logfile in subdirectory

Tags: texmaker

I'm using `Texmaker` under Windows with `latexmk`. I use the quickbuild option `latexmk + display PDF`. To let all auxiliary files be generated in a subdirectory called "Output" I changed the command Texmaker uses to

`latexmk -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %.tex --aux-directory=%/Output`.

This solution works perfectly fine, however, Texmaker seems not to find the generated logfile and displays the annoying message "Logfile not found". I found a workaround suggesting to put an empty file in the `.tex` file's directoy to suppress the error message, but I want to get informed about possible issues with the document. My question is therefore how I can let Texmaker find the actual log file in the "Output" folder. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ltx2any` can deal with exactly this situation https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any

Comment: It even preserve the ability to use `synctex`, see https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any/issues/75

Comment: Mhm, is there really no easier solution? :/ `ltx2any` looks powerful but I'm afraid I don't have the time at the moment to dive in as much as it seems to be necessary. Also: Does it work on Windows? (Which I am working with at the moment being the sole reason for me to ask this question as its Dropbox version does not support ignoring individual files -- only folders :|)

Comment: For windows you can find installation instructions: https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any/wiki I don't understand what you are trying to tell me with the dropbox sentence.

Comment: I don't know if there is an easier solution, I just know that lxt2any is designed to run in a subdirectory and is therefore really good at it.